# Modelling of a FSM using Verilog shows X

Tags: verilog, state-machine

Given the following FSM:

[image]

I am trying to model it using Verilog, and here is my trial:

```
module fsm (u,d,clr,clk,inc,dec,c);
  
input  u,d, clr,clk;
output reg inc,dec,c ;
// the state variables
reg y,Y; // y is the present state and Y is the next state
reg S0,S1;  

  // next state and output specifications 
 
  always @ (y,u,d) begin 
    
    case (y)
      S0 : if (u==1) begin
        Y= S1;
        inc=1;
        dec=0;
        c=1;
      end
      else if (u==0) begin
        c=0;
      end
      S1 :  if (d==1) begin
         Y= S0;
         inc=0;
         dec=1;
         c=0;
      end
      else if (d==0) begin
            c=1;
      end
   endcase 
  end 
  // state update
    always @(posedge clk,clr) begin
      if (clr) 
        y=S0;
      else 
        y=Y;
    end
    endmodule
```

Please let me know if my code correctly describes this FSM, and if there is any enhancement in the code please let me know it.

Here is an initial test bench code:

```
module tb();
 reg u,d, clr,clk;
reg inc,dec,c,y ;
  
  fsm ttb (.u(u),.d(d),.clk(clk),.clr(clr),.inc(inc),.dec(dec),.c(c));
  
     initial begin 
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
  end 
  
  initial begin //{
   clk=0 ; clr=0; #10
    clk=1; u=0 ; clr=0 ; d=0; #10
    clk = 0;#10
    u=1; clk=1; #10
   
    
    
    
    
    $finish;
    
    
    
    
  end //}
  
endmodule
```

The testbench code shows that there is something wrong. The present state variable `y` shows an undefined value 'X'. I don't know why. The same for the output variables `inc` and `dec`.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try to compile and simulate code? I would remove having the clr in your sensitivity list, unless you want it to be asynchronous.

Comment: @Laburtz yes I need it to be asynchronous. Do I leave it as it is ? Also what is the difference between this written line in my code and the '@(pos clk or clr) '?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several causes for the `X`'s.

In the design, you declared `S0` and `S1` as `reg`, but then you never assigned values to them.  A Verilog `reg` is initialized to `X`.  An FSM is conventionally coded using constant `parameter` values.  For example, change:

```
reg S0,S1;
```

to:

```
parameter S0=0, S1=1;
```

Your next state logic needs to assign values to `Y` in all cases (refer to `<---`):

```
  always @ (y,u,d) begin 
    case (y)
      S0 : if (u==1) begin
        Y= S1;
        inc=1;
        dec=0;
        c=1;
      end
      else if (u==0) begin
        c=0;
        Y= S0; // <-----
      end
      S1 :  if (d==1) begin
         Y= S0;
         inc=0;
         dec=1;
         c=0;
      end
      else if (d==0) begin
            c=1;
            Y= S1; // <-----
      end
   endcase 
  end
```

In your testbench, you need to assert the reset (`clr`=1):

```
  initial begin
    u=0; d=0;
    clk=0 ; clr=1; #10
    clk=1; u=0 ; d=0; #10
    clk = 0;#10
    u=1; clk=1; clr=0; #10
    $finish; 
  end
```

---

Addressing the comments on your Question regarding the asynchronous clear, you should change:

```
always @(posedge clk,clr) begin
```

to:

```
always @(posedge clk, posegde clr) begin
```